# Smarty assigned template variables

Tags: smarty

Looking through the Smarty debug console I discovered the variable {$u}, which contains the array video => "".

{$u} also contains photo, interview, etc. which is taken from the t1 table in the database.  The database does have a url in the video column, but it is not being captured in {$u}.  The problem right now is that I can't figure out where {$u} is populated.

What is the best way to find out where $u is populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't debug your code line by line (with Zend or Xdebug), try to search your PHP code for `->assign('u'`, `->assign("u"` or your Smarty templates for `{$u=`, `{assign name="u"`, etc...

Unfortunatly there is no way to make Smarty tell you automatically where a varible was declared.